# Is it possible to continuously embed $C^\infty(\mathbb{T}^n)$ as a vector space into $\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ by some "inverse" of periodization?

Tags: gn.general-topology, ap.analysis-of-pdes, schwartz-distributions

Let $\mathbb{T}^n$ be the $n-$dimensional torus and $C^\infty(\mathbb{T}^n)$ be the Frechet space of smooth periodic functions on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

According to p.298 of Folland "Real Analysis" 2nd Editition (1999), we can think of the periodization map $P : \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^n) \to C^\infty(\mathbb{T}^n)$ defined by
\begin{equation}
(P\phi)(x):=\sum_{\kappa \in \mathbb{Z}^n } \phi(x-\kappa)
\end{equation}
which is said to be continuous, and linear obviously.

Now let $\mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{T}^n)$ be the continuous dual space to $C^\infty(\mathbb{T}^n)$, equipped with the strong dual topology. Then, the textbook says that the adjoint of $P' : \mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{T}^n) \to \mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$ defined by
\begin{equation}
\langle P' F, \phi \rangle := \langle F, P\phi \rangle
\end{equation}
is in fact a bijection of $\mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{T}^n)$ into the space of "periodic" distributions $\mathcal{D}'_{per}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ where
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R}^n):=\{ T \in \mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R}^n) \mid \tau_{\kappa} T = T \text{ for all } \kappa \in \mathbb{Z}^n\}.
\end{equation}
Here, $\tau_\kappa$ is the translation operation by $\kappa$. There is no further information on the textbook regarding continuity of $P'$. However, I strongly suspect that $P'$ is a linear homeomorphism between $\mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{T}^n)$ and $\mathcal{D}'_{per}(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

Now, I also know that $C^\infty(\mathbb{T}^n)$ and $\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ are Frechet, nuclear and Montel and "reflexive" in particular. Thus, it seems possible to make $P$ bijective by restricting the domain to an appropriate subspace.

I found that $P$ itself is surjective according to p.300 exercise 24.c of Folland. However, how can I find the right domain on which $P$ becomes bijective? I believe that $C^\infty(\mathbb{T}^n)$ can be continuously embedded as a vector subspace into $\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ via this restriction of $P$.

All these things are essentially related to the regularity at the boundary and seem rather subtle.. Could anyone please help me?

Comment: Can you proofread your question and make sure you have $P$ and $P'$ straight?  You ask about using $P$ to embed $C^\infty(\mathbb{T}^n)$ into $\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ but that appears to go the wrong way, so did you mean $P'$ there?

Comment: That is exactly why I said "inverse" of periodization $P$.

Comment: You didn't say it.  The word "inverse" is not in your post.

Comment: Oh, in my title.

Comment: Well, if something is not only bijective but also an homeomorphism, we can freely take its inverse to reverse the direction.

Comment: Any surjective linear map is bijective on a suitable subspace just by linear algebra.